# Why can't I bake any kind of functional normal map?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I first noticed this issue when trying to bake a sculpted base mesh man to a retopologized one. I can't seem to achieve any kind normal bake that works at all. I've tried following multiple step by step baking guides on Youtube as well as the instructions in the Blender manual itself.

I've tried baking everything from the most complex shapes to smooth shaded high to low poly spheres. I've even tried exporting both high and low poly meshes to Xnormals for a different result with no luck. I'm sure its something simple and obvious, but I have been struggling with this for months. I prepared this hansom devil to demonstrate my problem.

[image] [image]
This is the .blend file if you want to take a look.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/omFyzR.jpg I did;nt see that option

Comment: I think i might've deleted you ranswer accidently

Answer (score 2):

- Switch from Blender 2.8 to 2.7 or 2.9, because 2.8 may be buggy with regard to baking.
- Create a new image for the normal, enable the *32 bit Float* option:

[image]

- Your bake *Extusion* value is much too high, bring it back to 0.1 (or give your *Ray Distance* a value of 0.1):

[image]

- In the *Shader Editor*, use a *Normal Map* node, not a *Bump* node.

[image]

- Bake:

[image]

The low-res without the *Normal* map:

[image]

With the *Normal* map:

[image]

Comment: https://snipboard.io/rcZ8ei.jpg      I followed all of the steps above, but result looks like this.

Comment: Also, under selective to active I  don't have the extrusion distance option. Just ray distance.https://snipboard.io/LuFJ1z.jpg

Comment: yes just use the Ray DIstance value, give it 0.1 (it's in world unit)

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd try that. That's this result. https://snipboard.io/GTaFhV.jpg

Comment: have you followed each step I describe? I've edited my answer... Also, are you using 2.8? I'm not sure but it may be buggy... Switch to 2.9 if you can (or use 2.7)

Comment: I used 32 bit float for the image, changed the bump node to normal map, and brought my ray distance down to 0.1 for that latest bake .jpg. I am using 2.83 which is supposed to be the stable long term solution one, but I will try it on2.9 now.

Comment: Yes I had problem with baking in 2.8, I'm not sure 100% but it may be buggy with baking

Comment: Well... It looks like this in 2.9. https://snipboard.io/jCwJeV.jpg .................I was able to bring extrusion down to 0.1 in 2.9 though.

Comment: please share your 2.9 file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117275/discussion-between-moonboots-and-zach-bowen).

Comment: I had to starte over in 2.9 because the file was too big for blend exchange. In doing so it seems to have worked.https://snipboard.io/UuFd0s.jpg .............Maybe 2.83 was the problem after all

Comment: Yes it may explain  ;)

Comment: Thanks for stickin with me friend. I really appriciate all your help moonboots.

Comment: Good luck for the rest, not sure about your topology but that's another topic  ;)